# mandi package crashing overleaf

Tags: overleaf

When I create a new file in Overleaf and add mandi package - the pdf won't compile. I'm getting this error:

```
(unicode-math)                Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.40 ...ror:nn {unicode-math} {unsupported-engine}
```

Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: do as the error message say: use xelatex or lualatex as engine.

Comment: BTW: `mandi` does not crash overleaf. You've just ignored section 6.3 of the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mandi/mandi.pdf#subsection.6.3) and this results in an error message. This error is independent from using Overleaf and not a crash.

Comment: in the  left sidebar in the overleaf menu there is a dropdown to choose lualatex instead of pdflatex